# Is it a bad idea to set external hard drive always spin?

Tags: external-hard-drive

I recently bought this external hard drive: [WD 1TB WD Elements Portable USB 3.0 Hard Drive Storage (WDBUZG0010BBK-NESN)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CI3BLPA)

This drive, which is connected to my laptop(Windows 8.1 x64) via USB, has a spin-down feature which puts the hard drive into sleep mode after 5 minutes of inactivity.

Because waking up from this sleep mode upon accessing the drive causes a delay, I want to know if it is harmful to set the drive so that it never goes to sleep and always spins?

By harmful I mean, will the drive fail sooner if it's always spinning and never goes to sleep?

Comment: Yes, you'll wear out the motor quicker.  Will it kill it before the drive becomes obsolete?  Hard to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will fail sooner.  The more you use something with mechanical parts, the more wear and tear it accumulates and therefore, it will fail sooner.

Now that doesnt mean it will fail in week, or a year, or in 5...

IMO, if you find the time to spin up as an annoyance, then let the drive stay active.  Just be sure to make backups as often as necessary.